# Adding further information in the context of the cell set

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'd like to be able to search the `[Employee Department]` `hierarchy` - within any of it's levels using a string: the following does this ok and finds all members related to the string "Control"

Now I have tried to add a cross join so that I can always see the department name for each of the rows and then `ORDER` by the department. If the commented section is uncommented I unfortunately get a full cartesian product - I only want the departments in the context of the members found by the filter - is this possible?

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelName] AS
        [Employee].[Employee Department].Level.Name
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelNumber] AS
        [Employee].[Employee Department].Level.Ordinal
   SET [Set_TargetEmp] AS
        {
        FILTER(
            [Employee Department].AllMembers,
                (
                InStr(
                    1, 
                    [Employee].[Employee Department].currentmember.name, 
                    "Control") <> 0
                ) 
            )
        }
SELECT
//  ORDER(
//      [Department].members,
//      [Department].[Department].MEMBERVALUE
//      ) 
//  *
    ORDER(
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Set_TargetEmp],
            [Employee].[Employee Department].[Department],
            SELF_BEFORE_AFTER
            ),
        [Measures].[LevelNumber],
        BASC
    ) as X
    ON 1,
    {
    [Measures].[LevelName],
    [Measures].[LevelNumber] 
    } ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use `Department` the `Department` dimension, and the `Employee Department` is in a different dimension named `Employee`, you get a cross product. Analysis Services only applies "autoexists" within the same dimension. Across dimensions, you must apply this logic explicitly like this:

```
   ORDER(
      Exists([Employee].[Department Name].[Department Name].members,
             [Set_TargetEmp]
            ),
      [Department].[Department].MEMBERVALUE
      )
```

for the commented block in your code should deliver what you want.

In case you have more than one measure group that relate to both the department and the employee dimensions, you should state the name of the measure group to use as the third argument of `Exists`. This is a string argument, hence this name should be included in quotes.

Comment: +1 @FrankPI ... glad you're back: hope you enjoyed your festive break - All the Best for 2014.

Comment: out of interest Frank - I've started to quote scripts using `[Adventure Works]` on SO in the hope that other MDX users will have this cube but sounds like from your post that this is not the case.

Comment: I have the AdventureWorks cube available (but actually was just posting out of my head without executing any MDX code). Nevertheless, it is a good idea to use AdventureWorks, as this way it is easy to run statements and check the results before posting in case one needs to try a bit.

Comment: @FrankPI hmmm - still can't get this to work. Seems to be giving me unexpected results before the above. I'll write a further question.

Comment: @FrankPI ....so taking a step back I've posted the following which uses the db `AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE` hopefully you can help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026900/self-before-after-why-arent-members-from-related-levels-returned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026900/self-before-after-why-arent-members-from-related-levels-returned)

Comment: @whytheq I just had edited my answer while you seem to have posted the other question. Sorry, I had not realized that you were using Adventure Works initially, as the `FROM` clause was only visible in the SO display when scrolling. I now switched to the `[Department Name]` attribute, which is separate from the `Employee Department` hierarchy, avoiding teh error message.