# SELF_BEFORE_AFTER - why aren't members from related levels returned?

Tags: ssas

Here is my script:

```
WITH 
    SET [Set_TargetEmp] AS
        {
        FILTER(
            [Employee Department].AllMembers,
                (
                InStr(
                    1, 
                    [Employee].[Employee Department].currentmember.name, 
                    "REUBEN") <> 0
                ) 
            )
        }
SELECT
    DESCENDANTS(
        [Set_TargetEmp],
        [Employee].[Employee Department],
        SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)
    ON 1,
    {} ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I know that `[Set_TargetEmp]` is the following:

[image]

So why when I wrap it in the function `DESCENDANTS` with the optional arg `SELF_BEFORE_AFTER` isn't reuben's related Department and Title not returned ?

---

**EDIT**

So I've simplified the above even further. Why doesn't the following return Reuben's title and department - I thought the point of `SELF_BEFORE_AFTER` was to also return relatives from the other levels of the hierarchy `[Employee].[Employee Department]` ?

```
SELECT
    DESCENDANTS(
        [Employee].[Employee Department].[Employee].[Reuben H. D'sa],
        [Employee].[Employee Department],
        SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)
    ON 1,
    {} ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Descendants` only returns descendants, i. e. members on a lower level than the first argument. What you require would be an [`Ancestor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145616.aspx). But - according to the documentation - the `Ancestor` and [`Ancestors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145620.aspx) functions do not allow a set as first argument. This means that - assuming your set is meant to possibly contain more than one member - you would have to use [`Generate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145526.aspx) to iterate over the members of `[Set_TargetEmp]`:

```
WITH 
    SET [Set_TargetEmp] AS
        {
        FILTER(
            [Employee Department].AllMembers,
                (
                InStr(
                    1, 
                    [Employee].[Employee Department].currentmember.name, 
                    "REUBEN") <> 0
                ) 
            )
        }
SELECT
    {} ON 0,
    Generate([Set_TargetEmp] as e,
             {Ancestor(e.Current, [Employee].[Employee Department].[Department])}
            )
    ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Actually, I am not using the `Descendants` function very often. But as far as I understand the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146075.aspx, it refers to second argument of `Decendants` (the level). For `Descendants([Department].&[Production], [Employee])`, `BEFORE` would be the `Title` level.

Comment: @FrankPI ok - I'll experiment....I thought `SELF_BEFORE_AFTER` referred to the first argument.

Comment: @FrankPI - basically reasoning behind the past couple of questions are that I want a script that is similar to the search function of Proclarity/Pyramid .... I type in a string and the script comes back with all relatives of higher and lower levels. I'll start another question as there might be a simpler way.

Comment: @FrankPI ....last comment I've put as a new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044594/search-allmembers-of-user-hierarchy-for-corresponding-set-return-a-related-mem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044594/search-allmembers-of-user-hierarchy-for-corresponding-set-return-a-related-mem)