# Search AllMembers of User Hierarchy - for corresponding Set return a related members from upper and lower levels

Tags: ssas, mdx

We have a `user hierarchy` with 3 levels (Level1 being the upper level - Level3 the lower)

Using the `FILTER` function I state a string, this string could be within the `member_name` of any member from any (or several) of the levels. This returns a set.

I would then like all members from the hierarchy related to each item in the set; both upper and lower levels.

I've also tried (unsuccessfully) to include a column that is always Level2 in the results as a reference and also an ordering column.

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelName] AS
        [DimensionX].[HierX].Level.Name
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelNumber] AS
        [DimensionX].[HierX].Level.Ordinal
    MEMBER [Measures].[MemName] AS //<<<<<not working as I want level 2 in the result set
        [DimensionX].[HierX].currentmember.membervalue
    SET [Set_Target] AS
        {
        FILTER(
            [DimensionX].[HierX].AllMembers,
                (
                InStr(
                    1, 
                    [DimensionX].[HierX].currentmember.name, 
                    "jesus") <> 0
                ) 
            )
        }
SELECT
//   ORDER(
//      Exists(
//      [AttributeHierX].members, 
//      [Set_Target]
//      ),
//    [AttributeHierX].[AttributeHierX].MEMBERVALUE
//      )
//*
    ORDER(
        DESCENDANTS(
            [Set_Target],
            [DimensionX].[HierX].[Level1],
            SELF_BEFORE_AFTER
            ),
        [Measures].[LevelNumber],
        BASC
    ) as X
    ON 1,
    {
    [Measures].[MemName], 
    [Measures].[LevelName],
    [Measures].[LevelNumber] 
    } ON 0
FROM [CubeX]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose a similar query on AdventureWorks delivers what you want:

```
WITH 
   MEMBER [Measures].[LevelName] AS
       [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Level.Name
   MEMBER [Measures].[LevelNumber] AS
       [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal
   MEMBER [Measures].[MemName] AS
       [Employee].[Employee Department].CurrentMember.Name
   SET [Set_TargetEmp] AS
        {
        FILTER(
            [Employee Department].AllMembers,
                (
                InStr(
                    1, 
                    [Employee].[Employee Department].currentmember.name, 
                    "WC4") <> 0
                ) 
            )
        }
SELECT
    {
    [Measures].[MemName], 
    [Measures].[LevelName],
    [Measures].[LevelNumber] 
    } ON 0,
    Hierarchize(
        Generate([Set_TargetEmp] as e,
            Ascendants(e.Current)
            +
            Descendants(e.Current, e.Current.Level, SELF_AND_AFTER)
        )
    )
    ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

I used `Hierarchize` to sort the result by hierarchy, as that seemed the most easy way for me to check the result. You may want to change that. As - in contrast to the `Descendants` method - `Ascendants` does not allow a set as the first argument, I used `Generate` to iterate along the set. Its default behavior (without a third argument of `All`), it eliminates duplicates, which I assumed is the behavior you need.

Comment: +1 Eliminating dupes was what I was hoping for but remembered last night that I'd forgot to mention then noticed in MDX Cookbook that there's a `DISTINCT` function but if this is not required even better.

Comment: ( thought you said you didn't use DESCENDANTS !! ... this is a sublime use of the function : `Descendants(e.Current, e.Current.Level, SELF_AND_AFTER)` )

Comment: @FrankPI - is `Hierarchize` or `+` getting rid of the duplicates?

Comment: @whytheq What is getting rid of duplicates is the `Generate` with two arguments, in contrast to `Generate(x, x, ALL)` with `All` as the third argument, which would keep duplicates.